# Determine if series converges or diverges

Tags: calculus

Trying to figure out if the following series converges or diverges. I tried using the limit comparison test but could not figure out if the series converges or diverges. Any help is much appreciated.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2e^{-2n} $$

Comment: Is Limit comparison the only method you know for analyzing convergence?

Comment: The [Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) should be easy and successful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to show you how to proof it converges and simultaneously how to calculate the limit. Let $0<|x|<1$. We know that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}.$$
Differentiate this expression twice on both sides to get 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2}=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}.$$
But $n(n-1)x^{n-2}=n^2x^{n-2}-nx^{n-2}$, and differentiating the above once gives 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-2}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{x-x^2}.$$
Adding this to the previous equation gives convergence of $\sum n^2x^{n-2}$ and 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 x^{n-2}=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{1}{x-x^2}.$$Multiply both sides by $x^2$ and fill in $x=\frac{1}{e^2}$ and use some high school algebra to get 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 e^{-2n}=\frac{2}{e^4}+\frac{e^4}{e^2-1}.$$

Answer (score 3):

How about integral test. Integral is rare and precious ! $\displaystyle \int_{1}^\infty x^2e^{-2x}dx$. Can you calculate this one using by part integration ?

Comment: +1  for coming up with a non-standard use of the Integral Test.  Rare indeed.  Just to say, though, that you do have to argue that the function is monotone decreasing, at least eventually. Else it isn't obvious that the  Riemann Sums fit inside the region.  Perfectly valid here, but it is worth a separate remark.

Answer (score 3):

The three first things I would try.

Approach 1: Comparison test. Compare to the geometric series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^ne^{-2n}
$$
Approach 2: Ratio test. Show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)^2e^{-2(n+1)}}{n^2e^{-2n}}\right|<1
$$
Approach 3: Root test. Show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^2e^{-2n}}<1
$$

Answer (score 2):

*HINT*

Apply the  $n-$th root test.

> $$\sqrt[n]{n^2e^{-2n}}=\sqrt[n]{n^2}e^{-2} \to e^{-2}<1$$ thus the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{+\infty}n^2.n^2e^{-2n}=0$$

$$\implies n^2.n^2e^{-2n}<1$$

for large enough $n $.

thus

$$n^2e^{-2n}<\frac {1}{n^2} $$

and comparison test.